# Why does the main() function in c++ not need to be called, it runs anyway?

Tags: c++

I have a really simple question. I have just started c++ and was wondering why the

```
 int main()
```

does not need to be called, it runs and prints out a

```
cout << "hello world";
```

without the function actually being called...?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `main` is the function the operating system calls to start your program.  If there wasn't a `main`, where do you think your program would start?

Comment: 1. Because that's how the standard specifies it. 2. Because the OS calls it. 3. But anyway, from where would you call it? Since in C++, you can't call a function outside another function, think about it -- there must be a function that is initially called automatically.

Comment: @Jay No, it can't return `void`.

Comment: The OS does not call `main()` directly.  The OS merely starts the process, which invokes the compiler's RTL startup code, which sets up the environment and then calls `main()` when ready.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't say the OS calls it directly. (Yes, I have programmed in assembler a bit. I've worked with `_start` and stuff. I've read parts of the Linux source tree.)

Comment: @Jay This was tagged c++, I don't know what that is.

Comment: @Jay No, it can't. Go search for it on SO. [It really really can't](http://ideone.com/KsWMfN). ("It compiles with some overly permissive compiler settings" and "it runs but has undefined behavior" does not imply that "it is allowed", smart ack.)

Comment: @H2CO3L: "I didn't say the OS calls it directly" - actually, you did: "Because the OS calls it". So did James: "main is the function the operating system calls". Both of which are wrong. The **OS** does not know anything about `main()` (or C/C++ for that matter).  All it knows about is the entry point that the **executable** exposes, which is not `main()` directly. `main()` is the entry point of the **C/C++ language** instead. The executable entry point invokes code that will eventually call `main()` when it is ready to do so.

Comment: @H2CO3 void main() is legal according to MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are trying to twist my words which is not appreciated. And you seem to be ignoring the fact that functions can call other functions, which in turn can call yet some other functions. Again, I did **not** say that the OS calls it *directly.*

Comment: @MikeD, Yeah, in the Microsoft-specific section. The standard does not allow it.

Comment: @MikeD But not according to the standard. No wonder Microsoft's horrible, proprietary implementation adds useless non-standard extensions.

Comment: @H2CO3 @chris Agreed. I only posted the link because many profs teaching "programming 101" use `void main()` are tied to VS.

Comment: @MikeD Surely. I didn't assert that "it doesn't work with the compiler Visual Studio uses". Because apparently, it does. Still, it's not generally, universally allowed.

Comment: its illegal bt its used thus my comment,"int main() or void main(),either.BUT ONE IS A MUST!" that was the base of this question not wether void main is illegal appreciated or should be used at all. run the code is MS propitiatory IDE VS and see lol

Answer (score 6):

It is called, just not by you.  Your compiler's RTL library calls it for you.  When the process begins running, the RTL's startup code executes, which sets up the environment as needed (sets up global variables, parses the command-line, etc), then calls `main()` when ready, and then exits the process after `main()` exits and the environment has been cleaned up.

Answer (score -1):

if you start a programm the current process (eg console/bash) is forking (ie making a new process which is an exact copy of itself beside the PID) after that the new (copied process calls your programm by calling the main() function